# Construct a predicate for $x \leqslant y$ given the set of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Z}$ and the symbols $0, 1, +, \cdot, =$

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

> 1) Given is the signature $σ=⟨0,1;+,⋅;=⟩$ and the standard interpretation
>   on the set of all real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. Construct the predicate
>   P(x, y) = $x⩽y$.
>
> 2) Given is the signature $σ=⟨0,1;+,⋅;=⟩$ and the standard interpretation
>   on the set of all integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Construct the predicate
>   P(x, y) = $x⩽y$.

At first this seemed like a trivial exercise, since I thought you could just write $P(x, y) = \exists z(x + z = y)$, but I quickly realised this only works with non-negative numbers. If I could somehow form a predicate $A(x)$ that is true if x is positive, then I would be golden, but that is a very similar task to the one I was trying to solve in the first place ($x > y$). So I am stuck in this loop. In order to write out that $x < y$, I need to write out that $x < y$. Therefore, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the reals is rather simple

$$P(x, y) = \exists z(x + z^2 = y)$$

For the integers, it's more subtle and uses a [Theorem of Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) that every natural number is a sum of $4$ squares of integers. Therefore

$$P(x, y) = \exists (z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4) (x + z_1^2 + z_2^2 + z_3^2 + z_4^2 = y)$$

Comment: I love this so much. This is way better than my answer, props for thinking of this! +1

Comment: @vrugtehagel: I am glad you like it!  So, the graph of the $\le$ relation is the projection of an algebraic set. Would you believe that the set of primes is also the projection  of an algebraic set?

Comment: I would, but that's pretty mindblowing indeed :D

Comment: @vrugtehagel: Yuri Matiyasevich's book is a good source

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that out, seems pretty interesting :)

Comment: @vrugtehagel: you can also look at his homepage https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~yumat/personaljournal/journal_content.php for his talk on Hilbert 10th

Comment: Majorly cool. Of course the case of $\Bbb R$ is clear, but I was totally clueless for $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @David C.Ullrich: Interestingly enough, there is no formula to get $\mathbb{N}$ inside $\mathbb{R}$...