# Non-negativity of an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Describe all non negative integers using only the constant symbols $0,1$, operations $+,\cdot$ and relation $=$ on $\mathbb Z$.
In the reals, a similar description is simple, we just say $x\geq 0\iff \exists y: y\cdot y = x$.

In the integers, however, that doesn't work. There's no $\sqrt{2}\in\mathbb Z$, for instance.

We could say
$$x\geq 0 \iff x=0\lor x=1\lor x=1+1\lor\ldots $$
but that's not satisfactory since it's not finite.

I always seem to be stuck defining it via itself, provided the expression is finite. What am I missing?

It would also be sufficient to describe negative integers.

Comment: Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703138/construct-a-predicate-for-x-leqslant-y-given-the-set-of-mathbbr-or-mat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **orangeskid**'s reference. [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem) does the trick.